# Can we change the 'flag topic' reasons

Tags: feature-request

When you flag a topic for moderator attention you have to go through the menus and pick a reason - these are usually way too narrow. For example if you flag something as off-topic you have a very limited number of reasons as to why it is off topic, e.g. it is a specific programming question or it belongs on another stack exchange. There is no option for "this is just completely off topic!"

Is there a way to edit these menus to add more reasons, or can we request reasons to be added?

Answer (score 1):

I'll look into it later tonight, thanks for the post.

Comment: Any progress on this topic?

Comment: @Phonon Any updates ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was added by another moderator:

> This question does not appear to be about signal processing within the scope defined in the help center.

but required the approval of someone else (e.g. me).  I've just approved it and it seems to have gone live.